# Update multiple fields based on condition in aggregation pipeline MongoDB Atlas trigger

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-nodejs-driver

I have the following pipeline that calculate the rank (sort) according to the `score` when the flag `update` is set to `true`:

```
  const pipeline = [
    {$match: {"score": {$gt: 0}, "update": true}},
    {$setWindowFields: {sortBy: {"score": -1}, output: {"rank": {$denseRank: {}}}}},
    {$merge: {into: "ranking"}}
  ];
  
  await ranking_col.aggregate(pipeline).toArray();
```

What i do next is to set the `rank` to 0 when the `update` flag is set to `false`:

```
ranking_col.updateMany({"update": false}, {$set: {"rank": parseInt(0, 10)}});
```

One of my document looks like this :

```
{
  "_id": "7dqe1kcA7R1YGjdwHsAkV83",
  "score": 294,
  "update": false,
  "rank": 0,
}
```

I want to avoid the extra `updateMany` call and do the equivalent inside the pipeline. MongoDB support back then told me to use the `$addFields` flag this way :

```
const pipeline = [
    {$match: {"score": {$gt: 0}, "update": true}},
    {$setWindowFields: {sortBy: {"score": -1}, output: {"rank": {$denseRank: {}}}}},
    {$addFields: {rank: {$cond: [{$eq: ['$update', false]},parseInt(0, 10),'$rank']}}},
    {$merge: {into: "ranking"}}
  ];
```

This is not working in my Atlas Trigger.
Can you please correct my syntax or tell me a good way to do so ?

Comment: You should remove `update: true` from your match stage `{$match: {"score": {$gt: 0}, "update": true}}`

Comment: I understand why you say so. But then, the `$setWindowField` would apply on all documents on my collection where `score > 0` which is not what i want because some ranks should not be updated... 
Is there a way to set the `$addFields` before the `$match` ? Or it doesn't make sense ?

Comment: If you want the `"$denseRank"` for only `"score": {"$gt": 0}`, isn't there a possibility that `"rank"` may be non-unique in the updated collection? What do you want to happen when `"score": {"$lte": 0}, "update": true`?

Comment: `denseRank` was a better option than `rank` because i can't allow gaps in my collection. ideally i would like something between both but i didn't find it.
I don't especially care about the `score` value, i mean the first criteria is `"update": true` and IF `"update": true`, then check the `score` to see if it's not 0 and do some updates. This improves performances over my collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This aggregation pipeline isn't particularly efficient (a fair amount of work in `"$setWindowFields"` gets thrown away - more comments about this below), but I think it does what you want.  Please check to make sure it's correct as I don't have complete understanding of the collection, its use, etc.

N.B.:  This aggregation pipeline is not very efficient because:

1. It processes every document.  There's no leading `"$match"` to filter documents.
2. Because of 1., `"$setWindowFields"` has to `"partitionBy": "$update"` and sort/rank the `"update": false` partition and `"$and": ["update": true, {"$lte": ["score", 0]}]` docs even though it is irrelevant.
3. All the irrelevant work is thrown away by just setting the `"update": false"` partition's `"rank"` to `0` and then excluding all the `"$and": ["update": true, {"$lte": ["score", 0]}]` documents from the `"$merge"`.

In a large collection, your original two-step update may likely be more efficient.

```js
db.ranking.aggregate([
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": "$update",
      "sortBy": {"score": -1},
      "output": {
        "rank": {"$denseRank": {}}
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "rank": {
        "$cond": [
          "$update",
          "$rank",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$not": [{"$and": ["$update", {"$lte": ["$score", 0]}]}]
      }
    }
  },
  {"$merge": "ranking"}
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JDYXm6BJmd7).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it's indeed working just fine. 
Can you please elaborate on the "fair amount of work" in `$setWindowFields` ? 
Please note that this query will run against a collection without millions of entries once per day from an Atlas Trigger, maybe more later...
The question i am asking here is that your aggregation is more performant that having my previous aggregation along with a `ranking_col.updateMany({"update": false}, {$set: {"rank": parseInt(0, 10)}});` query ?

Comment: @Tom3652 I updated the answer with an elaboration.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations i understand better a lot of things now. 
I will make some benchmark tests to see performances, but my you answered my question so i accept your answer.